# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. Need to show contacts in the same view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I have a View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller. It has a button and a table view. I need the contacts from the phone to load in the table view of this View Controller, but what is happening is that a new Navigation controller gets opened which displays the contacts. here's the code of the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)showContacts:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self; 

   // picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    //picker.modalInPopover = YES;
  //  [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    // [self displayPerson:person];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}
```

This is pretty standard code, I guess. How can I get the contacts to be displayed in the table view of the view controller that has the button, and not in a different controller?

Ok now I've done this:

```
 - (IBAction)syncContacts:(id)sender
    {
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        for (int i = 0; i < ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); i++) {
            ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
            NSString *contact = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(ref));
            NSLog( @"%@", contact);
            phoneContacts[i] = contact;
        }
         NSLog(@"%@",phoneContacts);
    }
```

I've changed the name of the method to syncContacts(for my convenience). The individual contacts are getting fetched and shown in the log when NSLog(@"%@",contact) is getting executed. But when I'm copying contact into phoneContacts array(mutable), it is not copying. I've tried addObject, insertObject:atIndex:, replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: etc, but still the phoneContacts array remains null. It has been initialized in didViewLoad(). Since nothing is getting stored in phoneContacts array, hence the table view is also not getting populated, as it uses the phoneContacts array.

Comment: all right, now values are getting into the array... the initialization was done using self.array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] that's why maybe the values were not going into the array when copied. But I'm still not getting anything in the table view. I'm gonna post the code for the table.

Comment: ok.. there was some issue with the delegate and data source. I was setting them from the storyboard. I removed that and set them using code inside syncContacts. Now I'm getting the contacts on the table view. But the problem is: I've 2 contacts in the address book and on presing the button on the view controller, it shows these 2 names on the screen. But when I press the button again, both those names get added to the view again. I want one contact to appear only once, no matter how many times the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to access the AddressBook framework programmatically and not through the AddressBookUI. You can set your tableView data source to be the result of this something like this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(
                                          kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          CFArrayGetCount(people),
                                          people
                                  );
```

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the contacts to be displayed in the table view of the view controller that has the button

You can't, by definition, if you use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, because what is displaying the contacts is a new view controller. New view controller = different view. In other words, this is the price for using the built-in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to save yourself from having to do a lot of work yourself.

The alternative is to invent your *own* interface. You will have to parse the contacts database and present the data *yourself*. That's not impossible. Here's the section of my book describing how to parse the contacts database:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch31.html#_address_book_database

But honestly, I think you should accept the compromise involved with using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController - adapt *your* interface to do things the way ABPeoplePickerNavigationController wants to be used. You'll save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: yeah I understand... but unfortunately, it is the requirement of my project.. I managed to get them on the same view controller, but i have some issues.. I've mentioned them above..

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by embedding the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController's view inside my own view controller:

```
- (void)embedContactsView {
    self.contactsController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.contactsController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];

    //embed the view
    [self addChildViewController:self.contactsController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.contactsController.view];
    //if your view controller is a navigation controller make sure you
    //hide the nav bar or it will overlap the contacts search.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

You can even make changes to the contact picker's navigation bar (such as hide the cancel button):

```
- (void)customiseContactsTabBar { //if this doesn't work be sure to call it in viewDidAppear
    //customise the apple picker a bit
    [self.contactsController.topViewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Everyone"];
    self.contactsController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(newButtonPressed)];
}
```

Whilst this approach is a little bit hacky it makes so much more sense than implementing an entire custom contact picker just so that it can be embedded in another controller.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
     ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

     [personController setDisplayedPerson:person];
     [personController setPersonViewDelegate:self];
     [personController setAllowsEditing:NO];
     personController.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
                                             nil];         
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:personController animated:YES];
 }];
}
```